# How to redirect request to Nginx to external server?

Tags: nginx, http-proxy, nginx-location

I have read the docs and seen numerous examples on how to proxy requests through Nginx, but I still can't make simple example work. 
When I enter a url like http://localhost:5050/maps/...., I would like Nginx make request to Google maps with that url.
Here's my config file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       5050;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            #root   html;
            #index  index.html index.htm;
            #access_log off;
            proxy_pass http://maps.googleapis.com;
            proxy_pass_request_body on;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }   
    }
}
```

But when I make a request to http://localhost:5050/maps/..., I got standard 404 page "not found". 
error.log file shows multiple entries for "The system can not find the file specified" , which is odd - I didn't ask for any files off disk. 
On top of that, I looked up in Fiddler - there's no outgoing requests to maps.googleapis.com.
What did I do wrong here? sample url is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

Answer (score 2):

I think the thing is - I wasn't restarting nginx correctly (I'm on Windows), so when I shutdown nginx.exe there were still a process left that continued serving requests. 
Anyway, here's a version that works for me:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  2000;

    server {
        listen       5050;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://maps.googleapis.com;
            proxy_pass_request_body on;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue in your original was this line: `proxy_set_header Host $host;` That would have sent 'localhost' as the Host header to google. Looks like your new one doesn't have that line.

Comment: @JoshuaDeWald I noticed that. So does it matter? Google doesn't recognize me? :)

Comment: Yeah, unless the google webserver is ignoring the host header (e.g. it only serves a single host) then it likely would cause a 404 or some other error.